# grid-template-areas split into 2 rows keep column widths

Tags: javascript, css

Im working on splitting a row of divs positioned by display:grid; into 2 or 4 rows.
Normally the divs are all on one row.

I currently have something working in theory. I split the rows by using grid-template-areas. All my columns have their grid-area set to col0 - colX, depending on how many columns I need. (user specific columns).

Some code:

```
function resizeEvent() {
    var windowWidth = window.outerWidth;
    var dashboardMinWidth = 0;
    var rowTargets = $(".enrollmentRow");

    var rowWidthLists = [];
    $(".enrollmentRow:first-child .enrollmentColumn:not(.enrollmentColumn[data-moduleType='emptyDummy'])").each(function (i, elm) {
        var attr = elm.getAttribute("data-columnWidth");
        dashboardMinWidth += parseInt(attr.split('|')[0]);
        rowWidthLists.push(attr);
    });

    var curState = "";
    if (windowWidth < dashboardMinWidth)
        if (windowWidth < (dashboardMinWidth / 2))
            curState = "quarter";
        else
            curState = "half";
    else
        curState = "full";

    var rowGridArea = "";
    var columnWidths = "repeat(auto-fit, minmax(130px,1fr))";
    var height = "auto";
    switch (curState) {
        case "quarter":
            var quarter = rowWidthLists.length / 4;
            for (var i = 0; i < rowWidthLists.length; i++) {
                if (i % quarter == 0)
                    rowGridArea += "\" \"";

                rowGridArea += (rowGridArea == "" ? "" : " ") + "col" + i;
            }
            break;

        case "half":
            var half = rowWidthLists.length / 2;
            var fix = 0;
            if (half % 1 != 0) {
                fix = 1;
                half = Math.trunc(half);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < rowWidthLists.length + fix; i++) {
                if (i == half + fix)
                    rowGridArea += "\" \"";

                rowGridArea += (rowGridArea == "" ? "" : " ") + "col" + i;
            }
            break;

        case "full":
            for (var i = 0; i < rowWidthLists.length; i++) {
                rowGridArea += (rowGridArea == "" ? "" : " ") + "col" + i;
                columnWidths += (i == 0 ? "" : " ") + "minmax(" + rowWidthLists[i] + ")";
            }
            height = "95px";
            break;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < rowTargets.length; i++) {
        rowTargets[i].style.gridTemplateAreas = '"' + rowGridArea + '"';
        rowTargets[i].style.gridTemplateColumns = columnWidths;
        rowTargets[i].style.height = height;
    }
}
```

How it looks in the css of a row, for the full version:

`grid-template:  "col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12 col13" / minmax(80px, 80px) minmax(155px, 155px) minmax(110px, 110px) minmax(80px, 80px) minmax(130px, 1fr) minmax(130px, 1fr) minmax(200px, 200px)minmax(160px, 160px) minmax(200px, 200px) minmax(110px, 110px) minmax(120px, 120px) minmax(115px, 115px) minmax(130px, 130px) minmax(130px, 1fr);`

The half version has a problem, because the `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(130px,1fr))` does not seem to work when the javascript puts it in, chrome dev tools says the value is invalid.

`"col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6" "col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12 col13" / repeat(auto-fit, minmax(130px, 1fr))`

For some reason the JS, insists to combine both grid-template-areas, grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows into one grid-template, and fails to do so.. because if I input the correct css directly via chrome dev tools, then it works fine..
Any suggestions?

Another thing that Would be nice to solve is the question of column widths once they have been split this way.

I tried the following css:

`grid-template: "col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6" "col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12 col13" / minmax(80px, 80px) minmax(155px, 155px) minmax(110px, 110px) minmax(80px, 80px) minmax(130px, 1fr) minmax(130px, 1fr) minmax(200px, 200px) minmax(160px, 160px) minmax(200px, 200px) minmax(110px, 110px) minmax(120px, 120px) minmax(115px, 115px) minmax(130px, 130px) minmax(130px, 1fr);`

The columns correctly get split, but the widths become the same.
I will try to illustrate this:

Original row
"|----|---|-----|--------|--|----|"

Expectation:

"|----|---|-----|"

"|--------|--|----|"

But unfortunately result:

"|----|---|-----|"

"|----|---|-----|" <---- these rows get squeezed or stretched based on the row above.

Any suggestions on why and how to fix this?

Comment: Why? Because that's the way Css-grid works. Flexbox might be a better option. Your expected result IS NOT A GRID.